# create_mutable/2 in SICStus Prolog

Tags: exception, prolog, iso-prolog, sicstus-prolog

The SICStus Prolog manual page on [mutable terms](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dlte_002dmut.html) states that:

> [...] the effect of unifying two mutables is **undefined**.

Then, why does `create_mutable(data,x)` fail?

Shouldn't that rather raise an `uninstantiation_error`?

I cannot think of a situation when above case is **not** an unintentional programming error (`X` vs `x`)... please help!

Comment: And rightly [so](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#uninstantiation_error).

Comment: @false. I fail to see the difference between the stream created by `open/4` and the mutable term created by `create_mutable/2`... will reread the text you linked.

Comment: @false. Or are you actually supporting my line of reasoning?

Comment: @false. "Then, why does ... fail?" "And rightly so."

Comment: @false. "Shouldn't that rather ..." "And rightly so."

Comment: @false. "I cannot think ..." "And rightly so."

Comment: @false. Makes *some* sense either way:)

Comment: It should raise an `uninstantiation_error`, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to "Why does `create_mutable/2` not throw an exception when output unification fails?" is just: Because this was how it was done when the feature was added to SICStus Prolog, and no one has made a strong case for changing this.

One important "difference between the stream created by `open/4` and the mutable term created by `create_mutable/2`" is that `open/4` has side-effects that are not undone if the output-unification of the call to `open/4` fails.

In this sense, `create_mutable/2` is somewhat more like `is/2` which also just quietly fails if the output argument is some non-numeric non-variable term, e.g. in `x is 3+4`. This seems to be the common, and traditional, way of handling output arguments in Prolog.

I agree that a non-variable as second argument is most likely a programming error. The next version of the SICStus IDE, [SPIDER](https://sicstus.sics.se/spider/), will warn for this (as it already does for `is/2`).

None of this, nor the example in the question, seems directly related to the cited documentation "[...] the effect of unifying two mutables [...]".

Comment: Thank you! The cited documentation appeared relevant to me. Here's why: if a "type-correct" use of `create_mutable/2` (`?- create_mutable(data,X), create_mutable(datb,X).`) in mode (-,-) does result in undefined behavior, then what good is (silent) failure with type-incorrect uses like `create_mutable(data,x)`?

Comment: @repeat Type-checking output arguments is questionable at best. Why should the `X = x, create_mutable(data,X)` goal throw an exception and the `create_mutable(data,X), X = x` goal fail?

Comment: @PauloMoura. Good point! I was focusing on eliminating a nasty error ... OTOH let me turn your question back to you: why should the `S=s, open(...,S)` goal throw an exception and the `open(...,S), S=s` goal fail? Full circle;)

Comment: @repeat Hum? Per's answer explains it: side effects that are not undone in the case of `open/3-4`.

Comment: @PauloMoura. Hoho. Technically correct! In practice, however, both "uses" are **errors** which fits 8.1.3.5 "predicate has a single mode and template, 
an argument whose mode is - is always associated with an error" like a glove.

Comment: @repeat A way forward would be to distinguish between `-` and `--` arguments with the former allowing a call with the argument bound (and thus a failure when the unification between the passed term and what would be the returned term fails) and the later requiring a call with the argument unbound (and thus an exception when that's not the case). In the presence of side effects not undone by backtracking, `--` would be used in the predicate specification. Otherwise, `-` could be used. That said, type-checking of output arguments is still a bad idea when side effects are not a concern.